# Discrepancy in sine values on processor based calculation and a calculator

Tags: ios, windows, calculator, spreadsheet, trigonometry

When I use a spread sheet (microsoft excel 2010, iphone), the value of sine shown is different than when I use a calcualtor (windows-os, iphone-native).

Eg:

a) sin(90) -> spread-sheet : 0.89399* / calculator : 1

b) sin(89) -> spread-sheet : 0.86006* / calculator : 0.99984

Given that by definition sin(90) is 1 and from what literature i've found online, i'm inclined to go with the value from the calculator but wanted to understand why the spread sheet on two different platforms (windows, ios) while consistent, behave differently from calculators on their respective platforms.

Regards

Ravindra

Comment: Degrees vs radians

Comment: Thanks. Can you post it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference comes from the argument being expected as degrees or radians.

Sine of 90 degrees is 1.

Sine of 90 radians is not 1.

Comment: Thanks. I remember resolving it once before but was not able to recollect it. Found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/my-excel-is-not-returning-the-correct-values-for/05d85d29-df61-4326-9b5f-7b1a4a48417a) link this time around.

Comment: Specifically, in the radian domain, `sin(90)` is equivalent to `sin(90 % (2*pi))`, or about `sin(2.0354)` -- since the period of the sin function is the 2π radian (or 360 degrees) angular rotation around a circle.